# Disabling IRQ#16 when removing DVI cable

Tags: debian-squeeze, interrupts, irq

I have a computer running with a Blackmagic Decklink card and a usbscreen. The problem i'm having is somethimes a irq conflict occurs and the OS disables irq16 witch both the decklink card and the usb screen is connected to. If i remove the dvi cable the server "beeps" and get this error:

```
[ 557.103401] irq 16: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[ 557.103530] handlers:
[ 557.103584] [<ffffffffa000c2d9>] (usb_hdc_irq+0x0/0x74 [usbcore])
[ 557.103735] [<ffffffffa019e06e>] (blackmagic_isr+0x0/0x30 [blackmagic])
[ 557.103867] [<ffffffffa000c2d9>] Disabling IRQ #16
```

After that the usb screen is very slow on update. And the decklink card is behving wierd after  that. I think it is very strange that all of this comes from unplugging the dvi cable.

I have moved the usb screen to another usb port ehci_usb3 and when i get the error only the decklink card i affected.

I'm runnuing debian 6.0.4 with a custom kernel. I have added a patch that allows writing to hidraw devices. I have used the same kernel patch on other kernels like ubuntu 10.04 withput problems.  I don't know that much about irq and if the problem is related to the kernel or the hardware either the motherboard or the decklink card

here is my output from lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
Memory behind bridge: fe400000-fe5fffff
Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sandy Bridge Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
Memory at fe000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point HECI Controller #1 (rev 04)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
Memory at fe729000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
Memory at fe700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
Memory at fe728000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at fe727000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
Memory at fe720000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
Memory behind bridge: fe600000-fe6fffff
Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
Memory at fe726000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cougar Point LPC Controller (rev 05)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cougar Point 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
I/O ports at f0d0 [size=8]
I/O ports at f0c0 [size=4]
I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
Memory at fe725000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cougar Point SMBus Controller (rev 05)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
Memory at fe724000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
I/O ports at f040 [size=32]
Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus

01:00.0 Multimedia video controller: Blackmagic Design Device a11b
Subsystem: Blackmagic Design Device a11b
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at fe500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Memory at fe400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [58] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-01-00-00-0a-35
Kernel driver in use: blackmagic_driver

03:00.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
Memory at fe600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [70] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable- Count=8 Masked-
Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff
Capabilities: [150] #18
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

And /proc/interrupts:

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  0:         58          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          2          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  8:          1          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:          4          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 16:     200026          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2, blackmagic0 
 17:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   xhci_hcd:usb1
 22:        334          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   HDA Intel
 23:    2402840          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb3
 27:       2400          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
 28:       2424          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      ahci
NMI:          0          0          0          0   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:    1213946    1031369     800145     621285   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:          0          0          0          0   Performance monitoring interrupts
PND:          0          0          0          0   Performance pending work
RES:      21023      55637      30534      18820   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:         66         67         89         92   Function call interrupts
TLB:     150716     125506     175584     150345   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:         18         18         18         18   Machine check polls
ERR:          0
MIS:          0
```

Comment: Sorry, kernels with custom patches targeted at the devices you're having problems with are too out of the "mainstream" for anyone on [SF] to help with.

Comment: You should probably bring this up to the Patch authors, or if they have support forums/mailing lists someone there may be able to help you too.